# runSequence is not working with gulp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

runsequence is the code below is not quite working?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  console.log('YOLO1');
  del(['build/*'], cb);
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
 console.log('YOLO2')
 return gulp.src('client/www/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  console.log('YOLO3')
  return gulp.src('client/index.js')
    .pipe(browserify({transform: 'reactify'}))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
  console.log('YOLO4')
  runSequence('clean', 'browserify', 'copy', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build'], function() {
  gulp.watch('client/*/*', ['build']);
  nodemon({ script: './bin/www', ignore: ['gulpfile.js', 'build', 'client', 'dist'] });
});
```

Current Output:

```
YOLO4,
YOLO1
```

DESIRED Output:

```
 YOLO4,
 YOLO1,
 YOLO3,
 YOLO2
```

I am not sure why runSequence is only executing the first task and unable to execute the rest? any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`del` does not take a callback, but returns synchronously: (see first sample in https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md)

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  console.log('YOLO1');
  return del(['build/*']);
});
```

Comment: This answer needs to be framed and put up on a wall. They recently changed the `del` behavior (using promises, no more callbacks) so a lot of tasks have to be updated.